# JPA join statement logic

Tags: jpa

Help this noob programmer. I've been using **JPA**, but there seems to be something bothering me with it's logic using the **join statement**.

For example, I have an entity named **`Person`**, with fields `name`, `age`, `gender`. And then for example in a query,

`select p from Person p join p.gender g`

**Note:** This is just an example why I'm confused.

The question is, why would you `join p` (person) and `p.gender`? what's the point? What results can it give?

Answer (score 1):

The point is in **joining multivalued relationships**. There is no point in joining on `p.gender`, I'm expecting `p.gender` to be attribute or single valued relationship (person can have only one gender).

But if you have joined on multivalued attribute e.g. `Collection<Order> orders` (person can have multiple orders), then you can search for persons which have some specific orders:

```
select p from Person p join p.orders o where o.price > 12000
```

This query will find all Persons which have some order with price higher than 12000.
You can't do it without join :

```
select p from Person p where p.orders.price > 12000
```

**This won't work** because `orders` is multivalued and you can't traverse it like this. You have to use **join** (or something else e.g. subquery).